# Photoshop: converting to a one-colour image w/ transparent background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, bitmap, monochrome, duotone

I have the following image with a transparent background:

[image]

I would like to convert it to just a single colour, but for it to fade to transparent rather than to different tints of the same colour. A bit like the below — I understand this is an illustration and not a photo, but it should give you the idea:

[image]

I've tried a duotone / monotone image with blue, but that gives me *blue and white*... not blue and transparent:

[image]

I've also tried setting the image as a bitmap with diffusion dither. This gives me just one colour (as I'd like it) but it looks really noisey and poor quality:

[image]

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Convert your document to grayscale.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the image to clipboard.
- Convert your document back to RGB (or CMYK if you prefer).
- Make a *solid color* adjustment layer. Select the color you want for the lines.
- Delete or hide the original image.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + left click the *layer mask* of the solid color layer to enter "mask mode".
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the image to the mask.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to deselect all.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to invert the mask.
- Click the solid color icon to exit "mask mode".
- Save your image as *psd* or *tif* with transparency.

[image]